# Select active working set with hotkey in Open Resource window

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys, working-set

I am using Eclipse (PDT) for developing websites in PHP. As I have many projects, I use working sets intensely. Besides this one, another of the best features of Eclipse is *Open Resource* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> by default), which also supports using working sets.

However, in the *Open Resource* window I have to use the mouse to click on the little black arrow in the upper right corner to roll down the working set menu. Is there a way to do the same using the keyboard? Assign a hotkey or maybe already has one?

Comment: I don't have an Eclipse at hand and so cannot try but... if you hit ctrl+shift+L twice, you should be shown a dialog with a list of all hot keys, you could filter on "select working set" or whatever the name of the command you try and assign a hotkey to, and assign it with an arbitrary binding... I don't know if this can be used with the drop down menus actions though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So that's CTRL+F10 and then the number of the working set in the list.

Comment: @abrahala this isnt really a shortcut to selecting the working set within the open resource window. Did you find out whats the short cut for that ?

Comment: @happybuddha actually I stopped using eclipse many years ago. As far as I can remember, the solution Gunther submitted was working perfectly at that time.